# UI Thread held up when using XAML Binding in a WinRT app

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, windows-runtime

I have a WinRT C# app with two ListViews. A simple way to represent it is that one ListView is a list of folder locations, and the second ListView details the directory structure inside that folder:

```
 ListView1     ListView2 (Contents of Folder 2)
 Folder 1      Folder a
|Folder 2|       File a
 Folder 3        File b
 Folder 4      Folder b
                 Folder c
                   File c
                 File d
```

Something like that.

I have a main ObservableCollection, which is a collection of folders. Each folder contains its own ObservableCollection, which is the data used in the second ListView.

ListView1 and 2 are bound the same, essentially:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource folderViewSource}}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fileViewSource}}"
```

With the CollectionViewSources being defined so:

```
<!-- The list of folders, used by the main ListView -->
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="folderViewSource"
    Source="{Binding FolderBinding}" />

<!-- The files and folders for a specific folder, used by the Files ListView -->
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="fileViewSource"
    Source="{Binding ElementName=folderListView, Path=SelectedItem.Files}" />
```

ListView1 populates fine, no problems.

ListView2 does bind correctly (it shows the files for the selected folder in the first ListView), but the binding is done on the UI thread. On my PC, it's tolerable if unpleasant. On my Surface RT, it can take a good 2 seconds.

The template used in the second ListView is quite fiddly, but I filtered it down to just a string and it was still a bit jerky on the Surface - obviously I need to move it off of the UI thread.

My first thoughts were to move the binding away from the XAML and do it in code, but I couldn't see any way to improve it - Windows is still creating the UI elements on the UI thread regardless of what I do.

I also looked at ISupportIncrementalLoading but that seems to be for dynamically loading new items as you scroll, etc.

I've been stuck for a while now, I've had things keeping me busy but I want to get back to this, but I can't figure this out. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: wow..... and they dropped WPF in favor of this WinRT thing because it was "supossedly faster"...

Comment: @alex - can you show your code for populating your 2nd observeablecollection (the slow one)?

Comment: @chue-x - the only code is the xaml binding. The second CollectionViewSource is bound to the SelectedItem.Files object from the first ListView, that is:

ListView1 is bound to an ObservableCollection of type Folder, ListView2 is bound to SelectedFolder.Files (which is another ObservableCollection). When I did it in C# instead, I just did essentially the same thing (get the selected item from the first ListView, get the Files collection, and then just
`this.DefaultViewModel["FileBinding"] = files;`.

Comment: @AlexHardwicke - I guess I'm missing something. How does your 2nd collection (files) get populated? I'm talking about the data structure itself, not the UI. You must have a function somewhere that gets the actual file names/attributes and puts them into the observeablecolletion, right?

Comment: Note that both ObservableCollections are populated with data when the app is launched, the left ListView always displays the data inside the outer Folder ObservableCollection, and the second ListView displays the contents inner ObservableCollection for the selected Folder in the first ListView. The lag is that all of the UI parts of the ListView entries in the second list are generated on the UI thread.

Comment: Specifically, the code for the inner (second) ObservableCollection is just this sort of thing:                 `String name = "Folder 1";
                File file = new File(null, String.Empty, name);
                name = "file.txt";
                File file2 = new File(file, "5", name);
                file.AddChild(file2);` - which as you can see, is fairly trivial, and run before the app is visible anyway.

Comment: UI elements are only created or usable on UI thread in all popular XAML frameworks. What makes you think that is slow? Do your animations freeze?

Comment: @Filip I have a PopInThemeAnimation which breaks, if I tap quickly on many items on the left ListView, it visibly lags (that is, I can stop and watch it catch up with me), and no UI responds while it's doing it (no highlights on mouseover etc.). ListView#2 is only visible if exactly 1 item is selected in ListView#1. If I select Folder1, then multi-select Folder2 (which makes ListView#2 disappear) and then unselect Folder2, it's perfect because ListView#2 already has the UI elements generated. If I unselect Folder1 instead, the UI thread hangs while it's generating the contents of ListView#2.

Comment: I ran out of characters - it's rather late here (3:45 AM), so I should really head to bed, but I'll try to take video to demonstrate what I mean and append it here later, but it really is just that ListView#2 is generating an awful lot of entries, each of which has a fiddly XAML layout, and while it's doing that generation it's completely hanging the UI thread. If that's how XAML does it, then I suppose I'll just have to manually code an async function to populate the ListView slowly rather than having it fully populate straight away or something. Just frustrating, this felt so elegant!

Comment: @AlexHardwicke - Your data load operation seems fairly simple. I just wanted to rule out any long data load operation that would block the UI thread.

Comment: @chuex Yeah, makes sense to check. Other than the XAML binding (and it's just bound to a property with `get { return files; }`, the only code that runs is in `listView_SelectionChanged`, and it's just `if (listView.SelectedItems.Count == 1) fileListView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; else fileListView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`. Definitely the XAML binding, and if I only have 1 file, the UI thread barely hangs, 2 items, it's a bit more noticeable, etc. etc.

Comment: I still don't think the problem is in the binding. I have used bindings all over WinRT and have never seen them causing performance issues. Maybe your ItemTemplate is loading images or is otherwise very complicated. Maybe storage access is somehow slowing down the machine (it's often fairly slow in general on a tablet). Maybe your ItemsPanel is customized to one that's not virtualized and you are generating tons of templated items. You can solve it by eliminating various possible factors (custom panel, rich item template, etc.). You can try to stagger the population of your bound list, etc.

Comment: @Filip I'm sure you're right - I have a rich template, and on my Surface in portrait, it can display 26 at once. Staggering the list sounds like what I need to do. I just tried staggering it by adding each File object to an observable collection one at a time with a simple await Task.Delay(50) between each addition. It works, but regardless of the delay value (even 1), the items appear slowly - about 0.1s per item, but it's better than having the entire UI lock up. I'll add a loading animation to make it clear. Thanks, Filip. If you have any tips I'd appreciate it, I'm new to C# and XAML.